# Как в DRF проверить есть ли такая запись в базе данных?

Tags: python, django-rest-framework

Всем привет. Я новичок в DRF. Подскажите пожалуйста как правильно сделать.
Я отправляю запрос на публичный API и полученный ответ сохраняю в базу данных. Мне нужно сделать проверку, что если в БД имеется такой же вопрос, к публичному API, то должны выполняться дополнительные запросы до тех пор, пока не будет получен уникальный ответ.

Вот мой views.py

```
@api_view(['POST'])
def my_view(request):
    input = MyInputSerializer(data=request.data)
    input.is_valid(True)
    count = str(input.data['questions_num'])
    tp_api = URL + count # адрес публичного api
    response_data = requests.get(tp_api).json()
    for res_data in response_data:
        if Questions_quiz.objects.filter(text_q = res_data['question']): # тут я проверяю, что если в базе есть поле с таким текстом, то должен выполниться повторный запрос к публичному API
            pass # тут наверное должен быть повторный запрос, но я не пойму как
        else: # а если поле с таким текстом нет, то сохраняю данные из запроса в базу
            quest = Questions_quiz(
                id_q = res_data['id'],
                text_q = res_data['question'],
                text_answ = res_data['answer'],
                pub_date = res_data['created_at'],
            )
            quest.save()
    return Response(response_data)
```

Comment: Попробуйте так if not Questions_quiz.objects.filter(text_q = res_data['question']).exists(): сохраняете в базу.

Comment: В итоге так и сделал, но что если условие не пройдёт, что тогда должно происходить?

Comment: @ Алексей Заикин  Что делать если такой объект уже есть в базе? пересоздавать его точно нет cмысла. можно заглушку pass поставить или else не писать вообще. Если такого объекта нет в базе - создаем его, если он есть - ничего не делаем. наверное так)))

Comment: @ Zhenia Kviatkivskyi
 Нет нет, тут задание, что если в базе уже есть такой объект, то нужно делать запрос к этому публичному API до тех пор, пока не попадётся уникальный объект))

Comment: Задача не до конца понятна. Вот вы сделали первый запрос, вам вернули список, скажем из 5 вопросов/ответов. Вы проходите по нему. Первого нет в БД - создали. Второй есть в БД, вопрос - вы говорите, что нужно сделать новый запрос, это ок, но что делать с оставшимися тремя вопросами из полученного списка? Пропускать вообще или тоже пробовать искать в БД? А если не нашли для, скажем, 3-го, то уже два запроса нужно делать? Далее вопрос: повторный запрос делать нужно на тот же URL или на какой-то другой?